# I have text in separate lines inside same box, How to make it all in one line

Tags: excel

Some of my text are in different lines inside same cell. I want them in single line. How do I bring them in single line ?

Example:
first cell contains:

```
Hi Ram, I want to go to movie today.
Are you willing to join?
If yes, let me know early.
```

Example:

Expected output:

```
Hi Ram, I want to go to movie today.Are you willing to join?If yes, let me know early.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New line in a cell A1 caused by alt+Enter for example, may be removed using a formula such as:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)," ")
```

Where A1 is the cell containing the text to be changed. You can enter the formula above in a different cell of course.

The parameter " " indicates 1 space to replace the line break. You could use any other character.

Another type of line break is CHAR(13). You can remove CHAR(13) using the same function again:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, CHAR(13)," "), CHAR(10), " ")
```

In case you had some spaces already before the new-line character, you need to wrap the above formula in a TRIM function like so:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)," "))
```

OR

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(13)," "),CHAR(10)," "))
```

*Always make a copy of your file before you apply formulas that could change the data.*

**Note-1:**

char(13) is officially called "carriage return" and char(10) is called "line feed".

CHAR(10) returns a line break on Windows, and CHAR(13) returns a line break on the Mac. This answer is for Windows. You can't visually see it but you can see its effect.

**Note-2:**

As @kojow7 answered, a text wrap can cause the text to appear on more than 1 line depending on the cell width and the text length. This answer does not resolve this case.

Related discussion can be found here: [Remove line breaks from cell](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/11/23/remove-spaces-excel/).

Answer (score 0):

Two things you may need to fix here: 1) Line breaks and 2) Text Wrapping

**To fix line breaks:**

- Select the cells that need to be changed
- Press CTRL+H to open Search and Replace
- In the Find box type CTRL+J to insert the line break character (it may look like nothing was inserted in the field, but it does insert a line break)
- Decide whether to replace the line breaks with a space or with nothing
- Press Replace All

**To turn off text wrapping:**

- Select the cells that need to be changed
- Go to the Home Tab
- In the Alignment Group check to see if the Wrap Text button is clicked.
- If it is, click on it again to deselect it.

Depending on your situation, you may need to fix either one or both of these.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your document it might contain linefeeds or carriage returns or BOTH.

Alexander Frolov (https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/03/remove-carriage-returns-excel/) has written a very good blog post about different technics of finding and removing linebreaks in an Excel file. We will use the “macro way” of doing that – as it is the one that works either on Windows AND Mac. The search replace method offered here too will not work on Mac but on windows.

- Add the below Macro to your document (slighlty modified from the original)
- Change the value of “ReplaceWith” from ” ” (space) to anything you like a linebreak to be replaced with.
- E.g. ReplaceWith = “-” will result in “Line1-Line2-Line3”
- Run the Macro (Extras > Macro) while all cells are selected.

  ```
  Sub RemoveCarriageReturns()

      ReplaceWith = " "    
      LinefeedChar = Chr(10)

      Dim recordRange As Range
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

      For Each recordRange In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
          If 0 < InStr(recordRange, LinefeedChar) Then
              recordRange = Replace(recordRange, LinefeedChar, ReplaceWith)
          End If
      Next

      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

  End Sub
  ```

If your separate lines are not gone by now please change "LinefeedChar" from "Chr(10)" to "Chr(13)" and run it again